# How can I show the list of all programs associated with a file type?

Tags: c#, wpf, registry

I am looking to build an open with list, just like in the windows context menu,for image files.So how could i get the list of all programs associated with a file type ?

[image]

Comment: You can find an implementation based on @WouterH answer here: http://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/Sandbox/249856-System-File-Association

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**First source**

If you look in the registry under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.bmp`.

The `(Default)` value will show you the default associated program. In my case, this shows 
`Paint.Picture`, which links you to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Paint.Picture`.

Under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.bmp` you'll also find the subkey `OpenWithList` which contains subkeys to "Open With" applications.

**Second source**

Under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts` you'll also find a list of fileextensions. Look for `.bmp`, a subkey `OpenWithList` exists there too. I think this source is what you need.

Comment: Where did you find this out?

Comment: First source was common knowledge (I think they did it that way since Windows 95). Second source is the new way (I believe) and you'll find several microsoft related articles that will mention it. F.e. Some microsoft articles talk about those keys, f.e. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/950505