# How to open the "Open With" dialog (Windows Store App)?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I want my app to let a user open a file with the "Open With" dialog even if it has a default application that opens that type of file. How can I achieve that?

Comment: I don't believe there's a way to do this with the authentic "Open With" dialog, but instead you'll have to mimic that behavior yourself. [This SO question & answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11896855/1189566) offers 2 ways to get the list of programs associated with a file type.

Comment: @sab669 No. Accessing the registry [can't be done by Windows Store apps](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d1f03ceb-49cf-4992-8723-3c400ab41d3f/access-the-registry-in-the-windows-store-app?forum=winappswithcsharp). And opening the "open with" probably _can_ be done because the Windows Photos app does it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call Launcher.[LaunchFileAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701465.aspx) and set LauncherOptions.[DisplayApplicationPicker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.launcheroptions.displayapplicationpicker.aspx) to true:

```
var options = new Windows.System.LauncherOptions();
options.DisplayApplicationPicker = true;

bool success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file, options);
```

Comment: and how can I add my WinRT app in desktop mode "Open with" apps list? Like for images, Photos app is present in "Open with" context menu.